# Oracle java function timeout

Tags: java

I have the next java function in my oracle database:

```
public String SnConectividad(String pServidor, int pPuerto)
{
        try{

            Socket s = new Socket();

                InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(pServidor,pPuerto);

                s.connect(addr, 7000);

            if (s.isConnected())

                    return "S";

        }catch(Exception e){}


        return "N";

    }
```

This function verify the internet connectivity before send a mail ... The problem is that the instruction timeout (7000 mils)  "s.connect(addr, 7000); "  not work..

So, calling this function   takes a long time to respond..

If I execute the same function on "netbeans" on windows... the time out work fine..

Any ideas.. '???

Comment: Could you please explain in what way it does not work? Is the 7000 argument ignored, I.e., interpreted as the default timeout? Or do you get an exception? Or a compilation error? Or yet something else?

Comment: It not work because when I run the database procedure that calls this function in Java, the process gets stuck for a long time without respecting the timeout of java procedure.

Answer (score 0):

use a `Thread` with `ExecutorService` :

```
   String flag="S";
   Runnable thrd=new Thread(){ @Override
    public void run() {
        try{

            Socket s = new Socket();

                InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(pServidor,pPuerto);

                s.connect(addr);

            if (s.isConnected())

                    flag="S";
                    return;

        }catch(Exception e){}


        flag="N";
    }};
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 Future future = executor.submit(thrd);
 executor.shutdown();
 try { 
   future.get(700, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
 }
 catch (Exception e) { 
   // Handle the exceptions 
 }
 if (!executor.isTerminated())
    executor.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: Could you please give some explanation why the original code would not work, and why this code _does_ work in the same situation?